# I am trying to fetch the result but it's showing incorrect result for the 2nd block. I mean if the condition falls within the 2nd block, then also not

Tags: javascript, if-statement

> The second block is not working.
> I am unable to understand why is else if block notvworking

```
let x = prompt('Enter number');
    
    if(x % 5 == 0){
        alert('Multiple of 5');
    }else if(x == '' || x == null){
        alert('Fill the no');
    }else{
        alert('Not a multiple of 5')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `'' % 5` or `null % 5` in your console (F12). You'll see they both equal 0, so you're entering the first `if` statement. Simply rearrange them.